# Apply patch to JBoss 5.1.0 GA

Tags: jboss5.x

I would like to add the [patch](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-2110?focusedCommentId=12565808#comment-12565808) to a JBoss 5.1.0 GA installation in order to do some tests.

My question : How can I add this patch? Couldn't find anything revlevant so far.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://www.jboss.org/ejb3/ejb3plugin to patch an existing JBoss 5.1.0GA installation with the latest bits and bobs.

Comment: After looking at the ejb3plugin , I don't think this is a solution because the patch i'm trying to apply isn't in any of the versions of the ejb3plugin(each plugin adds some patches to jboss)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the JBoss EJB3 source code, apply the patch to it, build the patched source code, and replace the existing code in your JBoss implementation.

This is not for the faint of heart! However, JBoss do provide instructions for [getting the source and building](http://www.jboss.org/ejb3/build), so give it a try.

Comment: Will give it a go.I appreciate the feedback.